# How do you find a line break in php?

Tags: php, arrays, string

Sorry I ain't that good with PHP yet, I tried this to find it and then put each line in an array

```
$translate="this
is in
multiple
lines";
$lastBreak=0;
$it=array();
$ci=0;
for ($i=1;$i<strlen($translate);$i++) {
    if strchr(substr($translate,$i,$i),"\n") {
        $it[$ci]=substr($translate,$lastBreak+1,$i-1);
        $ci+=1;
        $lastBreak=$i;
    }
}
```

help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$it = explode("\n", $translate);
```

http://php.net/explode

:)

Comment: To handle all line delimiters, use a regular expression in preg_split:
    $arry_lines = preg_split("/[\r|\n]+/", $translate);

Answer (score 5):

Updated:

it can produce an unexpected linebreak, this variation may help:

```
$arry_lines = explode("[\n|\r]", $translate);
```

Comment: [`split` is deprecated](http://php.net/split) as of PHP 5.3 and shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: The explode function does not allow a regular expression.  Use preg_split instead:

    $arry_lines = preg_split("/[\r|\n]+/", $translate);

Answer (score 0):

You can do a $string = nl2br($string) so that your line break is changed to

```
<br />.
```

Then you can manipulate the string, e.g. split it up by the first occurance of

```
<br />
```

like this:

```
list($first, $second) = explode('<br />', $string, 2);
```