# Find password and line break in php with regex

Tags: php, regex

Suppose i have a list of names and the corresponding randomly generated passwords having the following pattern:

`name:sucz2ReiG
name:ox9ZxnIka`

How can i obtain the password part with regular expression?

I know there is a similar thread here: [How do you find a line break in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972863/how-do-you-find-a-line-break-in-php), but i need to apply the pattern for each name in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty Easy:

```
$f = "name:sucz2ReiG name:ox9ZxnIka";

$p = preg_match_all('/[^:]*?:([^\s]+)/', $f, $matches);

var_dump($matches[1]);
```